# How to remove duplicates while sorting by unique datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am working with a fairly bad data source, the column that has the information I need is within a varchar(max) and is delimited. However, the data can be duplicated across multiple rows so I am trying to remove these duplicates.

This can be done by trimming the column I am interested in, as when I repeat occurs the "ID" gets re-appended to the end of the column. Then I am taking a distinct of that to, which I then concatenate the results; it isn't pretty.

Example data and the query I currently use [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d50af/3/0)

**Data Table**

```
| id | callID |                callDateTime |                             history |
|----|--------|-----------------------------|-------------------------------------|
|  1 |      1 | 2021-01-01 10:00:00.0000000 |         Amount: 10, Ref:123, ID:123 |
|  2 |      1 | 2021-01-01 10:01:00.0000000 | Amount: 10, Ref:123, ID:123, ID:123 |
|  3 |      2 | 2021-01-01 11:00:00.0000000 |       Amount:12.44, Ref:SIS, ID:124 |
|  4 |      2 | 2021-01-01 11:02:00.0000000 |       Amount:11.22, Ref:Dad, ID:124 |
|  5 |      2 | 2021-01-01 11:01:00.0000000 |       Amount:11.22, Ref:Mum, ID:124 |
|  6 |      3 | 2021-01-01 12:00:00.0000000 |                   Amount:11, ID:125 |
```

**Query**

```
select CallID, Concat([1],',', [2],',',[3])
from
(
  select CallID, historyEdit, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by callID order by callID) as rowNum
  from
  (
    select distinct callID, 
    substring(history, 0, charindex(', ID:',history)) historyEdit
    from test
  ) a
 )b
PIVOT(max(historyEdit) for rowNum IN ([1],[2],[3])) piv
```

**Result**

```
| CallID |                                                                   |
|--------|-------------------------------------------------------------------|
|      1 |                                             Amount: 10, Ref:123,, |
|      2 | Amount:11.22, Ref:Dad,Amount:11.22, Ref:Mum,Amount:12.44, Ref:SIS |
|      3 |                                                       Amount:11,, |
```

The issue is that I **need** to ensure the concatenate part is doing so in the order of when the events occurred. In the above you will see that CallID 2 is in the wrong order as Information 3 is coming before Information 2, I did try to sort the base table by callDateTime first and then run the query, however it does seem to yield somewhat random results. Sometimes it will be in the correct order, other times it won't be. I assume this is because I am not specifying any order by clause in the query.

Including the callDateTime in the results then causes the distinct not return the **unqiue** data rows as the callDateTime is still unique to that duplicated row of data

I am using SQL Server v12

**Desired Result**

```
| CallID |                                                                   |
|--------|-------------------------------------------------------------------|
|      1 |                                             Amount: 10, Ref:123,, |
|      2 | Amount:12.44, Ref:SiS,Amount:11.22, Ref:Mum,Amount:11.22, Ref:Dad |
|      3 |                                                       Amount:11,, |
```

Comment: Can you be clearer on what you are trying to accomplish?  What are you trying to deduplicate?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to break apart the history and recombine -- without duplicates -- for each `callid`.  If so, you can use `string_split()` and `string_agg()`:

```
select callid, string_agg(value, ', ')
from (select distinct t.callid, s.value
      from test t cross apply
           (select trim(s.value) as value
            from string_split(t.history, ',') s
           ) s
     ) st
group by callid;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8e4b1639f1ffaf378e4fdb5d28f31af3) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Result wise yes I believe you have understood what it is I am after, although I am not on this version of SQL Server so cannot access string_agg or string_split

Comment: It is also worth adding there can be "duplicated" data within the History field but the duplication in genuine. The only time it wont be genuine is if the entire History column for that given callID is an exact duplicate when removing the final "ID:xxx" parts which is why I was going down the distinct path

Comment: I have updated a few things in the question to make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

You could use `TOP` clause inside the `select` to order the records before pivoting the results if you are sure of the number of records like below:

```
select callID, historyEdit
   from
   (
     select distinct top 100000 callID, callDateTime,
     substring(history, 0, charindex(', ID:',history)) historyEdit
     from test
     order by callDateTime
   )t
```

Please see the results **[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=7d9489c69478901cc1e405d019664e4c)**.

Comment: The callDateTime will cause the distinct to still return the duplicate data as the callDateTime is unique to that row

Comment: @Chris but you can select 
one of those using group by as well (min or max callDateTime) if I got that correct. please check [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=6f9f8ad0aa7eea37309eca71e26249e6)

Answer (score 0):

One way to calculate the strings could be to CROSS APPLY using an ordinal splitter to separate the 'history' column into components which can be enumerated.  The result is very close to what was provided in the question.  Maybe the provided expected results aren't accurately representative?  Something like this

Ordinal splitter [described here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD]
--===== Define I/O parameters
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN
  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "zero base" and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT 0 UNION ALL
                 SELECT TOP (DATALENGTH(ISNULL(@pString,1))) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT t.N+1
                   FROM cteTally t
                  WHERE (SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter OR t.N = 0) 
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY s.N1),
        Item = SUBSTRING(@pString,s.N1,ISNULL(NULLIF((LEAD(s.N1,1,1) OVER (ORDER BY s.N1) - 1),0)-s.N1,8000))
   FROM cteStart s
;
```

query

```
with
unq_cte as (
    select distinct callID
    from #test),
exp_cte as (
    select callID, callDateTime , dl.*,
           row_number() over (partition by callID, dl.Item order by callDateTime) as rn
    from #test t
         cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(t.history, ',') dl)
select t.callID, 
       stuff((select ',' + case when rn>1 then '' else Item end
              from exp_cte tt
              where t.callID = tt.callID
                    and ltrim(rtrim(Item)) not like 'ID%'
              order by tt.callDateTime, tt.ItemNumber for xml path('')), 1, 1, '') [value1]
from unq_cte t
group by t.callID;
```

```
callID  value1
1       Amount: 10, Ref:123,,
2       Amount:12.44, Ref:SIS,Amount:11.22, Ref:Mum,, Ref:Dad
3       Amount:11
```